# Indexing values in a 2D array in python

Tags: arrays, indexing

This shouldn't be that hard.  Assume I have a 2D array:

```
a = [['1' 'George']
     ['5' ' ']
     ['7' 'Jose']
     ['5' ' ']
     ['7','Fred']]
```

I wish to find all the indexed values where `a[:,1] == ' '`

My best guess is:

```
missing_vals = a[a[:,' ']==' '
a[missing_vals]
```

I don't want the answer:

```
   ['5','5']
```

but the answer:

```
[1,4]
```

Meaning the 2nd and 5th elements of the array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
>>> a = [['1', 'George'],
...       ['5', ' '],
...       ['7', 'Jose'],
...       ['5', ' '],
...       ['7','Fred']]
>>> [i for i, [k,v] in enumerate(a) if v == ' ']
[1, 3]
```

Explanation:

We are asking for all indexes `i` in list `a` at which the element `[k,v]` in `a` has the element `v` equal to a space.

Comment: I am sorry.  I did not specify.  What I seek is the position of these in the array?  I am not looking for the answer ['5','5'] but this answer: [1,4] .  Meaning that if the array starts at 0, the positions for which the second column a == '  '.

Comment: No worries! I rewrote the answer for you.